# How do I suppress non-error messages in a custom R function

Tags: r

I am writing a custom R function which includes `messages` that are printed to the R console during the run and are designed to help the user figure out the steps taken by the program; they are not necessarily error messages, as exemplified below:

```
y        = a "data.frame"
stdNames = a set of standard column names on y

  if (length(setdiff(names(y), stdNames)) > 0) {

 cat('\ndata includes non-standard columns: selecting the standard columns...\n')

... <further code>

}
```

However, I would like to have the option to turn off these messages at will. Please advise, thank you!

Update: It was not my intention to suppress all the massages in my function. Therefore, I have wrapped some of them with `cat()`, leaving the rest as `message()`.

Comment: You could add a flag when you define the function: `f<-function(<other inputs>, messages = TRUE){<code here>}`, then in ur if statement u add: `if (<cases to check> & messages)`

Comment: Note these is a `message()` function that you should probably use rather than `cat()`. This would allow users to use `suppressMessages()`. Otherwise you need to track a boolean value whether or not to print the message.

Comment: @Baraliuh: Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @MrFlick: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Example of `message()` and `suppressMessages()` per @MrFlick:

```r
my_fun <- function(y, stdNames) {
  if(length(setdiff(names(y), stdNames)) > 0)
    message("data includes non-standard columns: selecting the standard columns...")
  
  head(y[, stdNames])
}

# no message expected
my_fun(iris, names(iris))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

# expected message
my_fun(iris, names(iris)[-1])
#> data includes non-standard columns: selecting the standard columns...
#>   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

# expected message suppressed by user
suppressMessages(my_fun(iris, names(iris)[-1]))
#>   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>